# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] despite giving full filepath

Tags: python, popen, python-3.7

So I have written a piece of code which first runs a powershell command to generate a UTF-8 version of a DAT file (have been having special character issues with the original file, hence the step). Following which I try to open the newly created file. But the issue is, I keep getting 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]' Initially I was only trying with the file name since the newly created file was in the same folder, but then i tried to generate the absolute path as well.

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content .\Own.DAT | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 Own1.dat"')

filepath = __file__
filepath = filepath[:-7]
with open(filepath+"Own1.dat", "r") as f:
```

I can confirm that filepath+"Own1.dat" is fetching the correct filepath. Yet can't figure out what the issue could be.
Edit: Someone asked for confirmation, here is the message i am getting:

```
C:\Users\Debojit\MiniConda3\python.exe "E:/My Documents/Work/essbase/ownership/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/My Documents/Work/essbase/ownership/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open(filepath+"Own1.dat", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/My Documents/Work/essbase/ownership/Own1.dat'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note: Curiously enough if i put the powershell command into a separate batch file, write a code in the python script to run it, the works without any issues. Here is the code i am talking about:

```
import os
import subprocess


from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("conversion.bat", cwd=r"E:\My Documents\Work\essbase\ownership")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

filepath = __file__
filepath = filepath[:-7]
with open(filepath+"Own1.dat", "r") as f:
```

The conversion.bat file contains the following

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content .\Own.DAT | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 Own1.DAT"
```

But I don't want to include a separate batch file to go with the python script.

Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Confirm your assumptions.  Make sure you fully-qualify your paths.

Comment: Have edited and pasted the error message I am getting. You will notice the filepath is being resolved properly and completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't figure out why the error was happening. But I found a workaround

```
with open("conversion.bat","w") as f:
    f.writelines("powershell.exe -Command \"Get-Content '" +fileName+ "' | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 Own1.dat\"")


from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("conversion.bat", cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

os.remove("conversion.bat")
```

Basically I would create the batch file, run it and then delete it once the file has been created. Don't why I have to use this route, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is unrelated to [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).  Popen runs asynchronously.  In one command, you are using `communicate()`, but in the other, you are not.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Since in both cases, the file is getting created as a result of the command. It's when I am trying to open the created file that the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Popen()` incorrectly.

If you want run a command and also pass arguments to it, you have to pass them as a list, like so:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-Command', ...])
```

In your code, popen tries to run a command literally named `powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content ...` which of course doesn't exist.

To use a simpler example, this code won't work:

```
subprocess.Popen('ls -l')
```

because it's trying to run a command literally named `ls -l`.

But this does work:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'])
```

Comment: I have tried your approach and the file creation works fine, however the error in question still persists. Additionally let me mention, Popen worked fine the way I was using it, since the file was getting created fine. As far as I understand the issue is not with file creation, but opening the created file.

Comment: If you're passing that whole string as the argument to `Popen`, I don't see how it can work.

Comment: It is working in my case though. I got the example from stackoverflow myself. I will try to find the link and put it here